# How to install Spark dependencies in Google AI Platform in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform

In the Google Colab, the current directory is `/myContent` and that directory has the following content:

```
setup.py      spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz     trainer/
```

In the trainer folder, it has `__init__.py  task.py`. `task.py` has my Python code, with `import pyspark`

Here is the code snippet in the `setup.py` which install the spark dependencies file:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz']

setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='My training application package.'
)
```

When I submit a training job to the Google AI Cloud running the code below at `/myContent` directory:

```
!gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
    --package-path $ACKAGE_PATH \
    --module-name $MODULE \
    --staging-bucket $STAGING_PATH \
    --scale-tier custom \
    --master-machine-type complex_model_l_gpu \
    --worker-machine-type complex_model_l_gpu \
    --worker-count 2 \
    --runtime-version 2.1 \
    --python-version 3.7 \
    --packages spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz \
    --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
    -- \
    --param_A=1 \
    --param_B=2 \
```

The job fails with an error message from the logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 447, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-build-b_xhvahl/setup.py'
```

1) I have submitted the `setup.py` to the Google AI platform, why it does not find that py file?

2) How to install the spark dependency file in the Google AI Platform beforehand? In the Google Colab Jupyter Notebook, I always run the following code in the cell:

```
# install spark
%cd
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq 
!wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.5/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!tar -xvf spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz > /dev/null
!pip install -q findspark
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/root/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I have submitted the setup.py to the Google AI platform, why it
>    does not find that py file?

I replicated the same error, and most probably the issue is caused by the file .tgz since the supported ones are only `.tar.gz` and `.whl`, see [manual build](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/packaging-trainer#manual-build) and [adding custom dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/packaging-trainer#adding_custom_dependencies). In `setup.py` you are referencing a zipped file (spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz), but as far as I know, the option `install_requires` should include a PYPI package or a directory with the required dependencies.

> 2. How to install the spark dependency file in the Google AI Platform
>    beforehand? In the Google Colab Jupyter Notebook, I always run the
>    following code in the cell:

In the Jupyter cell you are extracting the .tgz file and installing the spark binaries when you set up the `SPARK_HOME` variable. This is different to the procedure with the file `setup.py`. I noticed that the spark documentation says "*PySpark is now available in pypi. To install just run pip install pyspark*"; so, in order to use `import pyspark` you can opt to install it by:

- Using the file [pyspark-3.0.0.tar.gz](https://pypi.org/project/pyspark/#files) instead of spark spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz.
- Specifying pyspark in the setup.py file, for example: `install_requires=['pyspark>=2.4.5']`, and follow [the guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/packaging-trainer#working_with_dependencies) to properly configure the `setup.py` file.